# Why would IntelliJ IDEA give an 'Expression statement is not an assignment or call' error for System.out.println?

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea

Here is the code:

```
public class TryStuffOutHere
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Set the customer's name: ");
        }

}
```

When I type this, IntelliJ IDEA stops highlighting the string "Set the customer's name: " in all one color like it does for other string literals, and puts the red squiggly line between the words and displays "Expression statement is not an assignment or call." But, if I change the line to:

```
System.out.print("Set the customer's name: ");
```

The string again looks like a normal string assignment (all one color, no inspection flagging).

Even declaring the string separately and outputting the variable still produces the issue.

<strike>I've attached three images illustrating what I am talking about. Does anyone have any ideas about what is going on?</strike> <strike>Apparently, I am not allowed to post images yet. If you want/need screenshots, let me know. I'd be glad to sent them your way.</strike>

UPDATE (April 28th, 2013): Well, I now have enough points to add screenshots. So, here they are:

Image 1 
[image]

Image 2 
[image]

Image 3 
[image]

Image 4 
[image]

I've also discovered that the 10-12 second delay after invalidating the caches and restarting the IDE is because the IDE is still "updating the indices". After it does, the issue immediately pops up...sometimes. Further complicating it is that invalidating the caches and restarting has worked twice, until I quit and open the IDE again, at which point it resurfaces.

Comment: You may upload image in some other site and share the link here

Comment: community or ultimate edition? is it possible its picking up your string as some supported language? (sql or something)

Comment: `File` | `Invalidate Caches`, Restart.

Comment: @radai: The ultimate edition, version 12.1.2

Comment: @CrazyCoder: Thanks for the directions!

Comment: Have you installed WebStorm or something like that? I have same problem with WebStorm.

Comment: click anywhere on the marked text, wait for the red bulb to appear, select "edit inspection settings" from the bulb menu and see what plugin is responsible

Comment: Alt+Enter on the string, **Uninject language**.

Comment: @Gat: Yes I do happen to have WebStorm installed.

Comment: @Radai: Thanks for the tip on finding plugins that could be causing trouble!

Comment: @CrazyCoder: Your suggestion was the solution in my case, thanks! Worked flawlessly, even through restarting. I must have accidentally told it to inject the language. But that's the rule of thumb right? 99.9999999% of the time, it is user error, haha.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like it tries to interpret the code as some other language than java.

Do yo have some extra plugins active? Try to disable as many as possible just to make sure that none of them are interfering

Comment: A combination of this answer, Radai's and CrazyCoder's advice solved the problem. Instead of disabling everything, I did this:

1)Clicked on the string
2)Clicked the bulb (discovered alt+enter brings up the same menu)
3)Saw at the bottom of the list that 'Apple JS' was the language it thought was there.
4) Disabled 'Java Support' plugin, problem solved.
5) Re-enabled all the plugins, problem returned.
6) Clicked on the string, hit alt+enter and clicked on 'Uninject language', problem solved, even after restarting.

Thanks to everyone for the help! Hopefully this will someone else one day.

Answer (score 8):

I would try deleting the caches and restarting.  This sounds like a corrupt state in IntelliJ, I would also make sure you have the latest version 12.1

Comment: Ok, I verified that I am using version 12.1 Ultimate Edition. Your answer works for about 10-12 seconds and it suddenly reverts. So, I'm guessing it is on the right track, are there any more steps I might try taking?

Comment: That is "messed up" I have never seen this issue myself.  All I can think of is that you have a plugin which is confusing things. I suggest you try turning off any plugins you don't need and try again.